# Using a long filename, the FileDialog defaults to showing only the end. How to make it start at the beginning?

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I want to suggest two common filename syntaxes whenever this `OpenFileDialog` appears.

Setting the FileName:

```
dlg.FileName = "True Up -> S-CUSTXXX-YYYYMM-R; Non True Up -> CUSTXXX-YYYYMM-R"
```

Current result:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Is there a way to programmatically achieve the desired result?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way of doing this. The only way I can think of is for the user to press the HOME key on the keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, it conveniently scrolls to the actual filename...but thats not a legal file name or path there.

Comment: Ha. Yes. It isnt. it's late and I've been up since 0230. When can I retire?

Comment: Right, which is why I found it odd that it scrolled to halfway through the first "X"

Comment: Scrolling is not the problem.  You are using a character that is not legal in a file name.  The `>` character is reserved, it is used for output redirection by the command processor.  There are some others, Path.GetInvalidPathChars returns them.  The dialog simply tries to make hay of what you gave it.  Help it by providing a better name.

Comment: I considered that @HansPassant however that is actually not the cause. I tried removed the symbols and used your method `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` (Thank you, that's a helpful method in general) to double check that I had no Invalid chars. However the result is the same. `ImportDialog.FileName = "True Up looks like _ S CUSTXXX YYYYMM R Non True Up looks like _ CUSTXXX YYYYMM R"`

Comment: Just shift the focus to another control after filling the file name and the issue will get resolved

Comment: @Nobody How is this done? I can't find any control to reference, only properties which can't be focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible to complete this by shifting focus to a different control. However, I solved this problem by shortening the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Have two different menu options "Save True Up" & "Save Non True Up", and set the default filename according to which one the user picked. Ideally the user can just click save without editing the filename.

Comment: This is an `OpenFileDialog` not a `SaveFileDialog`. Unfortunately the user needs the freedom to open either a true up or non true up at any given time, but new users could use the direction if they are unfamiliar with the file name defaults.

Comment: In that case you might be better writing your own dialog box. It could have radio buttons for true-up/non-true-up, and you then fill a combobox or listbox with the matching filenames.